# When everyone exept me goes on my website they are forced to download a file with name application/octet-stream

Tags: php, .htaccess

As the title says,when people try to enter my website they are forced to download a file called application/octet-stream and they are faced with a white screen,When i enter it works perfectly,this havnt happend in the past , it have just commed recently.

In my .htaccess it says "deny from all"

Thanks for any help!
here is my index.php

```
<?php
// comment to show E_NOTICE [undefinied variable etc.], comment if you want make script and see all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT ^ E_NOTICE);

// true = show sent queries and SQL queries status/status code/error message
define('DEBUG_DATABASE', true); 

define('INITIALIZED', true);

// if not defined before, set 'false' to load all normal
if(!defined('ONLY_PAGE'))
define('ONLY_PAGE', false);

// check if site is disabled/requires installation
include_once('./system/load.loadCheck.php');

// fix user data, load config, enable class auto loader
include_once('./system/load.init.php');

// DATABASE
include_once('./system/load.database.php');
if(DEBUG_DATABASE)
Website::getDBHandle()->setPrintQueries(true);
// DATABASE END

// LOGIN
if(!ONLY_PAGE)
include_once('./system/load.login.php');
// LOGIN END

// COMPAT
// some parts in that file can be blocked because of ONLY_PAGE constant
include_once('./system/load.compat.php');
// COMPAT END

// LOAD PAGE
include_once('./system/load.page.php');
// LOAD PAGE END

// LAYOUT
// with ONLY_PAGE we return only page text, not layout
if(!ONLY_PAGE)
include_once('./system/load.layout.php');
else
echo $main_content;
// LAYOUT END
```

Comment: I have absolutely no idea where the download popup comes from, It's  not in this code you just posted. Why would you deny from all in your .htaccess? This makes no sence to me, It means that you block every user visiting your website...

Comment: I didn't make my htaccess,its there from the begginng

Comment: What happends if you delete the .htaccess? Also, trying searching for the text `application/octet-stream` in you application. That's where the forced download comes from.

Comment: The thing is,I have multiple htaccess,in cache , Config etc,but all says the same gonna go ahead and delete all. It still does the same thing for other people,but for me it dosn't work to even go on the web anymore

Comment: Perhaps clear the cache

Answer (score 0):

The file is being downloaded because the web server doesn't know what to do with so assumes whoever is requesting it wants to download it.

Try a handler to your htaccess file.

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .php
```

x-httpd-php5 may be different on your server.      ...-php53 or php54 for example

The multiple htaccess files probably aren't helping any.